# Debian Buster: Module fbcon not found

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, xorg.conf, debian-buster

System: ASUS Z390-PRO with i5-9600K and Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 and Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffee Lake) with driver i915.

I am running a clean install only with firmware-misc-nonfree and xrdp added. I have problems starting the X Server. I can access the tty[1-6] but there is only a blinking cursor on the graphics output post the GRUB menu. When I xrdp into the box, I can start my Xcfe4 desktop just fine.

Relevant output from lspci -v:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e98 (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
```

I got a `Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices` error in my /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux server 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 root=UUID=ae052e40-cf84-436b-a9ae-f58f6f4d85f6 ro quiet
Build Date: 05 March 2019  08:11:12PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 25 12:36:52 2020
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
(END)
```

When I use the following xorg.conf file, to specify the BusID...:

```
Section "ServerLayout"

    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0

EndSection

Section "Module"

    Load  "glx"

EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"

EndSection

Section "Device"

    Identifier  "Intel Graphics 3e98 i915"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0@0:2:0"

EndSection

Section "Screen"

    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Intel Graphics 3e98 i915"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"

EndSection
```

...I get a `Module fbcon not found` error in my /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log instead:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux server 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 root=UUID=ae052e40-cf84-436b-a9ae-f58f6f4d85f6 ro quiet
Build Date: 05 March 2019  08:11:12PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 25 14:22:21 2020
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
modprobe: FATAL: Module fbcon not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-6-amd64
```

This is my Xorg.0.log file:

```
[   399.543] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   399.543] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   399.543] Current Operating System: Linux server 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64
[   399.543] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 root=UUID=ae052e40-cf84-436b-a9ae-f58f6f4d85f6 ro quiet
[   399.543] Build Date: 05 March 2019  08:11:12PM
[   399.543] xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   399.543] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[   399.543]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   399.543] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   399.544] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 25 14:24:45 2020
[   399.544] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   399.544] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   399.544] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[   399.544] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   399.544] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   399.544] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics 3e98 i915"
[   399.544] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   399.544] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   399.544] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   399.544] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   399.544] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   399.544]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   399.544] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[   399.544] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   399.544] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   399.544] (II) Loader magic: 0x55f9f429be20
[   399.544] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   399.544]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   399.544]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   399.544]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   399.544]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   399.544] (++) using VT number 7

[   399.544] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   399.545] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:3e98:1043:8694 rev 0, Mem @ 0xa0000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00003000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   399.545] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[   399.545] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   399.545] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   399.546] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   399.546]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   399.546]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   399.546] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   399.546] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   399.546] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   399.546]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.99.917
[   399.546]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   399.546]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   399.546] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   399.546] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[   399.546] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[   399.546] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[   401.561] intel: waited 2020 ms for i915.ko driver to load
```

Maybe there is a problem with the Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver? In lspci it should say:

```
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

But that part is missing.

How can I proceed from here? Any suggestions are welcome.

**Update**

I finally realized that there is no support for Coffee Lake Graphics (Intel UHD Graphics 630) in Debian 10.2 yet. But I ended up using another/older graphics adapter for my Linux host and I am passing the integrated Intel adapter via IOMMU into a Windows 10 VM. That works very well.

Comment: Hello. I believe you are using an older command? This source says you should use the randr extension instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478663/modprobe-fatal-module-fbcon-not-found-number-of-created-screens-does-not-matc

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try. But I think `xorg.conf` is just an initial configuration that can than be adjusted with `xrandr` commands.

Comment: I only have access to the machine from an RDP session and `xrandr -d :0` only returns: `Can't open display :0`